# Can you have multiple responses shown in the Grafana Query inspector

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, victoriametrics, metricsql

I have multiple queries in promQL and influxQL in the edit panel in Grafana. All of the results are shown on the graph above the queries. I also want to see the results of these queries in the Query inspector window in Grafana, but only one of the results shows. I can see that Grafana calculates all of the results but overwrites them in the Query inspector window. Is there a way to display the results of all queries in the Query inspector?

Answer (score 0):

If you use VictoriaMetrics, then multiple queries can be written inside parenthesis `(q1, ..., qN)`. This works similar to `UNION` statement from SQL - time series with duplicate names and duplicate sets of labels are removed from the response. For example, if `q1` returns `m{foo="bar"}` and `m{foo="baz"}`, while `q2` returns `m{foo="bar"}` and `m{x="y"}`, then `(q1, q2)` response will contain three time series:

- `m{foo="bar"}`
- `m{foo="baz"}`
- `m{x="y"}`

While the `m{foo="baz"}` from `q2` will be removed from the output even if it has different datapoints.